# Callstack overflow, works only on small array pairs, how would I make it take 10k array pairs?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, statistics, promise, callstack

I am attempting to do some data processing on the client side but it has proven to be more difficult than I originally thought.

I use a double for loop so it will call the following function 31^2 times and store a table of promises.

```
    var getPearsonsCorrelation = function(x, y){
        // var deferred = $q.defer(); 
        //I commented the promise statements out
        //so you can copy paste into your own browser to try a small array

        var shortestArrayLength = 0;
        if(x.length === y.length){shortestArrayLength = x.length;}
        else if(x.length > y.length || y.length < x.length){
            deferred.reject('array lenghts are not the same size');
        }

        var xy = [];
        var x2 = [];
        var y2 = [];
        var sumX = 0;
        var sumY = 0;
        var sumXy = 0;
        var sumX2 = 0;
        var sumY2 = 0;

        var partOneCounter = 0;
        var partTwoCounter = 0;

        function partThree(sumX, sumY, sumXy, sumX2, sumY2){
            var step1 = (shortestArrayLength * sumXy) - (sumX * sumY);
            var step2 = (shortestArrayLength * sumX2) - (sumX * sumX);
            var step3 = (shortestArrayLength * sumY2) - (sumY * sumY);
            var step4 = Math.sqrt(step2 * step3);
            var answer = step1 / step4;
            console.log(answer);
            //deferred.resolve(answer);
        }

        function partTwo(xy, x2, y2){
            if(partTwoCounter>= shortestArrayLength){
                partThree(sumX, sumY, sumXy, sumX2, sumY2);
            }else{
                sumX += x[partTwoCounter];
                sumY += y[partTwoCounter];
                sumXy += xy[partTwoCounter];
                sumX2 += x2[partTwoCounter];
                sumY2 += y2[partTwoCounter];
                setTimeout(partTwo(xy, x2, y2), 0);
                partTwoCounter++;
            }
        }

        function partOne(partTwo){
            if(partOneCounter>=shortestArrayLength){
                partTwo(xy, x2, y2);
            }else{
                xy.push(x[partOneCounter] * y[partOneCounter]);
                x2.push(x[partOneCounter] * x[partOneCounter]);
                y2.push(y[partOneCounter] * y[partOneCounter]);
                setTimeout(partOne(partTwo), 0);
                partOneCounter++;
            }
        }
        partOne(partTwo);
        //return deferred.promise;
    };
```

I got this script from stevegardner, however as it currently is it is blocking javascript.
http://stevegardner.net/2012/06/11/javascript-code-to-calculate-the-pearson-correlation-coefficient/

In my attempt to make it async javascript, I now get callstack overflow errors instead. Is there some work around for this?

Appreciate it!

Comment: Instead of invoking a function as a parameter to setTimeout, try passing it.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and it worked great. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use setTimeout do not invoke the function. You should pass a noninvoked function.

```
calculate function(){
/* --- */
}

setTimeout(calculate(),0) //wrong
setTimeout(calculate,0) //right

//And if you want to pass in params into the setTimeout

setTimeout(function(){
   calculate(params)
},0)
```

@Benjamin Gruenbaum thanks!

Comment: Also in this case, it may be better to spawn a web worker rather than do this on the main thread